# sbl-style colon comma after name

Tags: biblatex

I am using biblatex-sbl. In the notes, the first quotation of an "article" and "incollection" should be this:

> Krause,Jens-Uwe: “Die Spätantike (284-565 n. Chr.),” in: Gehrke,
>   Hans-Joachim/ Schneider,Helmuth (eds.): Geschichte der Antike. Ein
>   Studienbuch, Stuttgart 52019,429–499.

In the following notes, it should be:

> Krause,Jens-Uwe, “Die Spätantike (284-565 n. Chr.),” 429–499.

In short: I want that after the author name of a reference of an "incollection" (and also of an "article") a colon should be shoen; in all other notes it should be a comma.

Here is my MWE:

```
\RequirePackage[patch]{kvoptions} 
\documentclass[openany]{book} %headsepline

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{Gehrke.19,
  author = {Gehrke, Hans-Joachim},
  title = {Geschichte der Antike. Ein Studienbuch},
  location = {Stuttgart},
  edition = {2},
  date = {2019}
}
@incollection{Krause.19,
  author={Krause, Jens-Uwe},
  gender = {sm},
  title={Die Spätantike (284-565 n. Chr.)},
  editor = {Gehrke, Hans-Joachim and Schneider, Helmuth},
  date = {2019},
  booktitle = {Geschichte der Antike. Ein Studienbuch},
  location = {Stuttgart},
  keywords = {sekundaer},
  pages={429--499},
  edition={5},
}
@article{Krug.19,
  author = {Krug, Alex},
  date = {2019},
  title = {The Time},
  journaltitle = {Revue Today},
  shortjournal = {RT},
  volume = {18,1},
  pages = {9--38},
}
@review{Wellhausen.1906,
  author={Wellhausen, Julius},
  revdauthor = {Ban, Paul},
  revdtitle={Selection, Paris/ Leipzig 1905},
  journaltitle = {Göttingische gelehrte Anzeigen},
  shortjournal = {GGA},
  volume={16,2},
  keywords = {sekundaer},
  date={1910},
  pages={16--18},
}
@thesis{Witz.2001,
  author = {Witz, John},
  title = {Narratives},
  type = {phdthesis},
  institution = {Princeton University},
  date = {2001},
  keywords = {sekundaer},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{babel} %Kommentar 


\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
%\usepackage[german=guillement]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[style=sbl,backend=biber,sblfootnotes=false,ibidpage=true,sorting=nyvt,url=false,isbn=false,doi=false,clearlang=false,uniquename=false]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\newbibmacro*{bookeditor}{%
  \printnames{bookeditor}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{cite:incollection}{%
  \ifentrytype{seminarpaper}
    {}
    {\toggletrue{inentrytype}}%
  \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \iftoggle{blx@usefullcite}
    {}
    {\let\ifciteseen\@firstoftwo}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byauthor/byeditor+others/bytranslator+others}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{in:}%
     \iffieldundef{booktitle}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{bookeditor}%
        \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{bybookauthor/bybookeditor+others/bybooktranslator+others}%
        \newunit}%
     \usebibmacro{volume+partof}%
     \iffieldundef{maintitle}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{maineditor}%
        \usebibmacro{maintitle}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{bymainauthor/bymaineditor+others/bymaintranslator+others}}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{volumes}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{shortseries+number}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{note}%
     \usebibmacro{parens+publisher+location+date}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{ebook}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{addendum}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{volume+part+pages}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{isbn}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \toggletrue{inentrytype}%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \ifentrytype{classictext}
    {\usebibmacro{byauthor}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
    {\usebibmacro{byauthor/byeditor+others/bytranslator+others}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \iffieldundef{booktitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bookeditor}%
     \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{bybookauthor/bybookeditor+others/bybooktranslator+others}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+partof}%
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{maineditor}%
     \usebibmacro{maintitle}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{bymainauthor/bymaineditor+others/bymaintranslator+others}}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{shortseries+number}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{ebook}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+part+pages}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{isbn}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    togl {relatedseen}
    or
    not togl {bbx:related}
  }
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}


\xpatchbibdriver{book}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {}
  {}


\renewcommand*{\subtitlepunct}{\addperiod\space} % Punkt zw Titel und Subtitel in Bibliogr.
\renewcommand*{\sqspace}{} % kein Abstand bei Seitenzahl mit "f." 

\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1} % Buchtitel nur normal - ohne Formatierung
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{#1} % Buchtitel nur normal - ohne Formatierung
\DeclareFieldFormat[review]{title}{#1} % Buchtitel nur normal - ohne Formatierung
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{maintitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{shorttitle}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{shortbooktitle}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{shortmaintitle}{#1} 

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} % vorher last-first in Klammern
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}



\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash\space} 
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim} 

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}{\textsc} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}{\textsc} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}{\textsc} 

%%%%%% Verursacher nr. 1 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}} 
%\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace} 
%%%%%% Verursacher %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash\space} 
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim} 

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}{\textsc} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}{\textsc} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}{\textsc} 


%%\renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{% 
  %%\ifboolexpr{ 
   %% test \ifuseeditor 
   %% and 
   %% not test {\ifnameundef{editor}} 
  %%} 
    %%{\ifciteseen{% 
      %% \usebibmacro{ifidemused} 
       %%  {} 
        %% {\printnames[labelname]{editor}}% 
    %% }{\renewcommand*{\namedashpunct}{\addcomma\space}% 
      %% \usebibmacro{dashcheck} 
        %% {\bibnamedash} 
        %% {\usebibmacro{ifidemused} 
         %%   {} 
           %% {\printnames{editor}% 
             %%\usebibmacro{savehash}}}% 
      %% \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}% 
       %%\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}% 
      %% \usebibmacro{withname}{editor}% 
     %%}% 
     %%\clearname{editor}} 
    %%{}} 


\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  reprint = {ND:}
}

  % Put reprint information in parentheses and change beginning punctuation to a
% space
\newcommand*{\begrelateddelimreprint}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{related:reprint}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% Set \newunitpunct to comma and remove parentheses around publication info
\renewbibmacro*{related:reprint}[1]{%
  \entrydata*{#1}{%
    \usedriver
      {\renewbibmacro*{related:init}{}%
       \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%
       \renewbibmacro*{parens+publisher+location+date}{%
         \newunit
         \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}}
      {\ifbibliography
         {\thefield{entrytype}}
         {cite:\thefield{entrytype}}}}}

% use family, given and change \newunitpunct to a point just for related
% entries (I have serious misgivings about this as it seems very
% inconsistent.)
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretobibmacro{cite}
  {\iffieldequalstr{relatedtype}{reprint}
     {\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}%
      \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}}
     {}}
  {}
  {}



\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{ 
  editors = {Hgg\adddot}, 
} 


\renewbibmacro*{parens+publisher+location+date}{% 
\newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}% 
  \iffieldequalstr{relatedtype}{reprint} 
    {\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addsemicolon\space}% 
     \newunit 
     \usebibmacro{related:init}% 
     \usebibmacro{related}% 
     \global\toggletrue{relatedseen}} 
    {}} 

\renewbibmacro*{origpublisher+location+date}{% 
  \printlist{origlocation}% 
  \setunit*{\addspace}% 
  \usebibmacro{origdate}% 
  \newunit} 

\newbibmacro*{real+publisher+location+date}{% 
  \printlist{location}% 
  \iffieldundef{howpublished} 
    {} 
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}% 
     \printfield{howpublished}}% 
  \setunit*{\addspace}% 
  \usebibmacro{date}% 
  \newunit} 


\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{% 
  \ifboolexpr{ 
    not test {\iffieldundef{origpublisher}} 
    or 
    not test {\iffieldundef{origlocation}} 
    or 
    not test {\iffieldundef{origyear}} 
  } 
    {\usebibmacro{origpublisher+location+date}% 
     \setunit{\addspace}% 
     \printtext[parens]{% 
       \bibstring{reprint}% 
       \setunit{\addspace}% 
       \usebibmacro{real+publisher+location+date}}} 
    {\usebibmacro{real+publisher+location+date}}} 

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[inlexicon]{% 
  skipbib=false, 
} 

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inlexicon}{% 
  \usebibmacro{begentry}% 
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}% 
  \newunit 
  \usebibmacro{title}% 
  \newunit 
  \printfield{note}% 
  \newunit 
  \usebibmacro{xrefshortmaintitle+xrefshortbooktitle}% 
  \newunit 
  \usebibmacro{volume+pages}% 
  \newunit 
  \printfield{addendum}% 
  \usebibmacro{finentry}% 
}

\xpatchbibdriver{cite:book}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:commentary}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:suppbook}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:incollection}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{book}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
  \xpatchbibdriver{suppbook}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \printdate
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{pubstate}}

\begin{document}
  \null\vfill
  Filler text \autocite{Gehrke.19}.
  Filler text \autocite{Gehrke.19}.
  Filler text \autocite{Krause.19}.
  Filler text \autocite{Krause.19}.

  Filler text \autocite{Wellhausen.1906}.
  Filler text \autocite{Wellhausen.1906}.
  Filler text \autocite{Witz.2001}.
  Filler text \autocite{Witz.2001}.
  Filler text \autocite{Krug.19}.
  Filler text \autocite{Krug.19}.
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not as easy as it should be for `biblatex-sbl`. I have not yet supported `\nametitledelim`. See https://github.com/dcpurton/biblatex-sbl/issues/99. You have to patch every driver that should have the colon. Should it remain as a dot in the bibliography or should that also be a colon for `article` and `incollection`?

Comment: In the bibliography it should remain as it is. I am wondering also if also "book" can be adapted in the same way: the first note should be e.g.: Gehrke, Hans: Spätantike, Stuttgart 52019, 14. - and the following notes: Gehrke, Spätantike, 14. The bibliography should remain without changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this we need to do three things. This isn't quite as obvious as I would have suspected, which makes me wonder if there are some other issues with context sensitive delimiters in `biblatex-sbl`. (e.g., I would have thought that I should have to specify I want context `citecommand` with `\printdelim`, but it doesn't work without this.

1. Change the delimiter before the title in your new `cite:incollection` driver from `\newunit` to `\nametitledelim` in context `citecommand`.

   ```
   \setunit{\printdelim[citecommand]{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}%
   ```
2. Patch the `cite:article` and `cite:book` (and any other) driver to use `\nametitledelim` in context `citecommand` instead of `\newunit` before the title.

   ```
   \xpatchbibdriver{cite:article}
     {\newunit
      \usebibmacro{title}}
     {\setunit{\printdelim[citecommand]{nametitledelim}}%
      \usebibmacro{title}}
     {}
     {}
   \xpatchbibdriver{cite:book}
     {\newunit
      \usebibmacro{title}}
     {\setunit{\printdelim[citecommand]{nametitledelim}}%
      \usebibmacro{title}}
     {}
     {}
   ```
3. Define `\nametitledelim` in context `citecommand` so that it prints a colon only for the first note and a comma for subsequent notes.

   ```
   \DeclareDelimFormat[citecommand]{nametitledelim}{%
     \ifciteseen
       {\addcomma\space}
       {\addcolon\space}}
   ```

## Working Example

Updated Working Example which hopefully addresses all your requirements from last few questions. Includes code tidy up and fixes. I switch to the font Linux Libertine O which has small caps.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{Gehrke.19,
  author = {Gehrke, Hans-Joachim},
  title = {Geschichte der Antike. Ein Studienbuch},
  location = {Stuttgart},
  edition = {2},
  date = {2019}
}
@incollection{Krause.19,
  author={Krause, Jens-Uwe},
  gender = {sm},
  title={Die Spätantike (284-565 n.~Chr\adddot)},
  editor = {Gehrke, Hans-Joachim and Schneider, Helmuth},
  date = {2019},
  booktitle = {Geschichte der Antike. Ein Studienbuch},
  location = {Stuttgart},
  keywords = {sekundaer},
  pages={429--499},
  edition={5},
}
@article{Krug.19,
  author = {Krug, Alex},
  date = {2019},
  title = {The Time},
  journaltitle = {Revue Today},
  shortjournal = {RT},
  volume = {18,1},
  pages = {9--38},
}
@review{Wellhausen.1906,
  author={Wellhausen, Julius},
  revdauthor = {Ban, Paul},
  revdtitle={Selection, Paris/ Leipzig 1905},
  journaltitle = {Göttingische gelehrte Anzeigen},
  shortjournal = {GGA},
  volume={16,2},
  date={1910},
  pages={16--18},
}
@thesis{Witz.2001,
  author = {Witz, John},
  title = {Narratives},
  type = {phdthesis},
  institution = {Princeton University},
  date = {2001},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=sbl,sblfootnotes=false,ibidpage=true,sorting=nyvt,url=false,isbn=false,doi=false,clearlang=false,uniquename=false]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Font and language set up %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Bibliography option modifications %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[inlexicon]{% 
  skipbib=false, 
} 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Driver modifications %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% New cite:incollection, incollection,and inlexicon drivers

\makeatletter
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{cite:incollection}{%
  \ifentrytype{seminarpaper}
    {}
    {\toggletrue{inentrytype}}%
  \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \iftoggle{blx@usefullcite}
    {}
    {\let\ifciteseen\@firstoftwo}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim[citecommand]{nametitledelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byauthor/byeditor+others/bytranslator+others}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{in:}%
     \iffieldundef{booktitle}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{bookeditor}%
        \setunit{\printdelim[citecommand]{nametitledelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{bybookauthor/bybookeditor+others/bybooktranslator+others}%
        \newunit}%
     \usebibmacro{volume+partof}%
     \iffieldundef{maintitle}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{maineditor}%
        \setunit{\printdelim[citecommand]{nametitledelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{maintitle}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{bymainauthor/bymaineditor+others/bymaintranslator+others}}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{volumes}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{shortseries+number}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{note}%
     \usebibmacro{parens+publisher+location+date}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{ebook}%
     \newunit
     \printfield{addendum}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{volume+part+pages}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{isbn}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
\makeatother

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \toggletrue{inentrytype}%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim[bib]{nametitledelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \ifentrytype{classictext}
    {\usebibmacro{byauthor}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
    {\usebibmacro{byauthor/byeditor+others/bytranslator+others}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \iffieldundef{booktitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bookeditor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{booktitle}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{bybookauthor/bybookeditor+others/bybooktranslator+others}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+partof}%
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{maineditor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{maintitle}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
     \newunit
     \usebibmacro{bymainauthor/bymaineditor+others/bymaintranslator+others}}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{shortseries+number}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{ebook}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+part+pages}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{isbn}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    togl {relatedseen}
    or
    not togl {bbx:related}
  }
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inlexicon}{% 
  \usebibmacro{begentry}% 
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}% 
  \newunit 
  \usebibmacro{title}% 
  \newunit 
  \printfield{note}% 
  \newunit 
  \usebibmacro{xrefshortmaintitle+xrefshortbooktitle}% 
  \newunit 
  \usebibmacro{volume+pages}% 
  \newunit 
  \printfield{addendum}% 
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

% Various driver patches
%   - use nametitledelim in cite:article and cite:book
%   - remove edition

\xpatchbibdriver{cite:article}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim[citecommand]{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {}
  {}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:book}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim[citecommand]{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {}
  {}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:review}
  {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
   \newunit}
  {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
   \setunit{\printdelim[citecommand]{nametitledelim}}}
  {}
  {}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:thesis}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim[citecommand]{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {}
  {}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:book}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:commentary}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:suppbook}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{book}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}
  \xpatchbibdriver{suppbook}
  {\newunit\printfield{edition}}
  {}{}{}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Punctuation and delimiter modifications %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\renewcommand*{\subtitlepunct}{\addperiod\space} % Punkt zw Titel und Subtitel in Bibliogr.
\renewcommand*{\sqspace}{} % kein Abstand bei Seitenzahl mit "f." 

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash\space} 
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim} 
\DeclareDelimFormat[citecommand]{nametitledelim}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {\addcomma\space}
    {\addcolon\space}}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{%
  \addperiod\space}

% Change reprint beginning punctuation to a space
\newcommand*{\begrelateddelimreprint}{\addspace}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Field format modifications %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1} % Buchtitel nur normal - ohne Formatierung
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{#1} % Buchtitel nur normal - ohne Formatierung
\DeclareFieldFormat[review]{title}{#1} % Buchtitel nur normal - ohne Formatierung
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{maintitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorttitle}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{shortbooktitle}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{shortmaintitle}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}

% put reprint information in parentheses
\DeclareFieldFormat{related:reprint}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} % vorher last-first in Klammern
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}{\textsc} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}{\textsc} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}{\textsc} 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% String modifications %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  editors = {Hgg\adddot}, 
  reprint = {ND:},
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% bibmacro modifications %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newbibmacro*{bookeditor}{%
  \ifnameundef{bookeditor}
    {\ifnameundef{editor}
       {}
       {\printnames{editor}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}%
        \clearname{editor}}}%
    {\printnames{bookeditor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}%
     \clearname{bookeditor}}}%

\newbibmacro*{maineditor}{%
  \ifnameundef{maineditor}
    {\ifnameundef{editor}
       {}
       {\printnames{editor}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}%
        \clearname{editor}}}%
    {\printnames{maineditor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}%
     \clearname{maineditor}}}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \printdate
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{pubstate}}

% Set \newunitpunct to comma and remove parentheses around publication info
\renewbibmacro*{related:reprint}[1]{%
  \entrydata*{#1}{%
    \usedriver
      {\renewbibmacro*{related:init}{}%
       \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%
       \renewbibmacro*{parens+publisher+location+date}{%
         \newunit
         \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}}
      {\ifbibliography
         {\thefield{entrytype}}
         {cite:\thefield{entrytype}}}}}

% use family, given and change \newunitpunct to a point just for related
% entries (I have serious misgivings about this as it seems very
% inconsistent.)
\xpretobibmacro{cite}
  {\iffieldequalstr{relatedtype}{reprint}
     {\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}%
      \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}}
     {}}
  {}
  {}

\renewbibmacro*{parens+publisher+location+date}{% 
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}% 
  \iffieldequalstr{relatedtype}{reprint} 
    {\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addsemicolon\space}% 
     \newunit 
     \usebibmacro{related:init}% 
     \usebibmacro{related}% 
     \global\toggletrue{relatedseen}} 
    {}} 

\renewbibmacro*{origpublisher+location+date}{% 
  \printlist{origlocation}% 
  \setunit*{\addspace}% 
  \usebibmacro{origdate}% 
  \newunit} 

\newbibmacro*{real+publisher+location+date}{% 
  \printlist{location}% 
  \iffieldundef{howpublished} 
    {} 
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}% 
     \printfield{howpublished}}% 
  \setunit*{\addspace}% 
  \usebibmacro{date}% 
  \newunit} 

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{% 
  \ifboolexpr{ 
    not test {\iffieldundef{origpublisher}} 
    or 
    not test {\iffieldundef{origlocation}} 
    or 
    not test {\iffieldundef{origyear}} 
  } 
    {\usebibmacro{origpublisher+location+date}% 
     \setunit{\addspace}% 
     \printtext[parens]{% 
       \bibstring{reprint}% 
       \setunit{\addspace}% 
       \usebibmacro{real+publisher+location+date}}} 
    {\usebibmacro{real+publisher+location+date}}} 


\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite{Gehrke.19}.
Filler text \autocite{Gehrke.19}.
Filler text \autocite{Krause.19}.
Filler text \autocite{Krause.19}.
Filler text \autocite{Krug.19}.
Filler text \autocite{Krug.19}.
Filler text \autocite{Wellhausen.1906}.
Filler text \autocite{Wellhausen.1906}.
Filler text \autocite{Witz.2001}.
Filler text \autocite{Witz.2001}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: In theory you would almost never have to use the optional argument of `\printdelim`. The code is quite long, so I'm not keen on going through it just now, but maybe the argument-less version didn't work because the `nametitledelim` has a generic definition and a definition for `bib`.

Comment: @moewe, yes. I plan to investigate further.

Comment: That said, if the defined drivers `cite:<type>` are used in citations with `\usedriver` as their name suggests they should override the current `...cite` context and should use `bib` ... so maybe everything is more or less working as intended ...

Comment: You have changed the style of the incollection: Now, you have e.g. in the notes and the bibliography: KRAUSE, JENS-UWE: „Die Spätantike (284­565 n. Chr.)“, in: Geschichte der Antike. Ein Studienbuch. Herausgege­ben von HANS-JOACHIM GEHRKE/ HELMUTH SCHNEIDER. Stuttgart 52019, 429–499. But this should stay in this way: KRAUSE, JENS-UWE: „Die Spätantike (284­565 n. Chr.)“, in: GEHRKE, HANS-JOACHIM/ SCHNEIDER, HELMUTH (Hgg.): Geschichte der Antike. Ein Studienbuch. Stuttgart 52019, 429–499.

Comment: @anonym, Well, your MWE in the question doesn't give that either… And it it still contains errors that I mentioned in my previous answer (missing `\makeatletter`…`\makeatother` and wrong `babel` set up). I will try and go through all your questions and fix everything up.

Comment: You don't get small caps because (at least my version of) Times New Roman does not contain small caps.

Comment: Thanks again! It is possible to change "thesis" and "review" in your example only for the first mention in the note? Actually, in the 1st note of the review it is: WELLHAUSEN, JULIUS, Rezension von XYZ, Paris/ Leipzig 1910, von BAN PAUL, GGA
168,2 (1906), 164–168. => to: WELLHAUSEN, JULIUS: Rezension von XYZ, Paris/ Leipzig 1910, von BAN PAUL, GGA
168,2 (1906), 164–168.

Comment: And  WITZ, JOHN,  Narratives (Diss., Princeton University
2001), 165–178. => to  WITZ, JOHN: Narratives (Diss., Princeton University
2011), 165–178.

Comment: Finally, it is possible to change all bibliography entries (book, article,..) in the field of the name? I want that all entries in the bibliography begins with a colon, e.g: WELLHAUSEN, JULIUS: ... => all entries should have after their name a colon –

Comment: @anonym, or do you mean all entry types in the notes? You just have to patch every `cite:…` driver like I did in point 2 above.

Comment: @anonym, I've added the patches for `@thesis` and `@review`. You should be able to add any other entry types you need yourself. It's probably best to mark this question as solved and ask new and more specific questions for other changes you need. This site isn't well suited to continually updating questions and answers. And in general questions should be specific, rather than a more general "how do I implement this entire style in `biblatex`.