# Colon (:) instead of period (.) after author with biblatex sbl

Tags: biblatex

I have the same problem that is described here: [Colon (:) instead of period (.) after author with biblatex, alphabetic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28892/colon-instead-of-period-after-author-with-biblatex-alphabetic)

My problem is that this solution does not work for biblatex-sbl and so I wanted to ask how can I have global (for all entries in the bibliography (book, incolection, thesis, review,...); the notes should not be changed) a colon after the name?

This question was also asked here: https://golatex.de/umstellung-auf-biblatex-sbl-in-fussnoten-und-literaturverz-t21903.html but the answer was only that it is very complicated. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{XXX}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}{\addcolon\space}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {}
  {}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Engelmann:2013,
  author      = {Engelmann, Hans and Bengelmann, Franz},
  title       = {Die Sicht},
  location    = {Berlin},
  publisher   = {De Gruyter},
  date        = {2013},
  series      = {Gamma Omega, I. Reihe: Alpha},
  shortseries = {GO.A},
  number      = {4},
}
@mvlexicon{TRE,
  editor     = {Schwertner, Siegried M.},
  title      = {Theologische Realenzyklopädie},
  shorttitle = {TRE},
  volumes    = {36},
  location   = {Berlin and New York},
  publisher  = {De Gruyter},
  date       = {1976/2004},
  shorthand  = {TRE}
}
@inlexicon{Poe:1994,
  author = {Poe, Edgar},
  title  = {Art. Dichtung},
  volume = {2},
  pages  = {9--343},
  xref   = {TRE}
}
@review{Well.19,
author={Well, Jan},
revdauthor = {Ban, Peter},
revdtitle={Select. Tomus I, Paris 1950},
journaltitle = {Göttingische gelehrte Anzeigen},
shortjournal = {GGA},
volume={18,2},
 keywords = {sekundaer},
date={1826},
pages={14--18},
}
@article{Wink:2000,
  author       = {Wink, Gert},
  title        = {„Mega“. Anmerkungen},
  shorttitle   = {„Mega“},
  journaltitle = {Critica storia},
  shortjournal = {Cs},
  volume       = {34,1},
  date         = {2000},
  pages        = {9--24}
}
@article{Wink:2003,
  author       = {Wink, Gert},
  title        = {„Mega II“. Anmerkungen},
  shorttitle   = {„Mega“},
  journaltitle = {Critica storia},
  shortjournal = {Cs},
  volume       = {41,4},
  date         = {2003},
  pages        = {11--22}
}
@incollection{peterson:1993,
  author     = {Peterson, David},
  title      = {The Motif of Fulfilment and the Purpose of Luke-Acts},
  shorttitle = {Motif of Fulfilment},
  pages      = {83-104},
  volume     = {1},
  maintitle  = {The Book of Acts in Its First Century Setting},
  editor     = {Winter, Bruce W.},
  location   = {Grand Rapids},
  publisher  = {Eerdmans},
  date       = {1993},
}
@book{Pritchard:1969,
  editor    = {Pritchard, James B.},
  title     = {Ancient Near Eastern Texts Relating to the Old Testament},
  edition   = {3},
  location  = {Princeton},
  publisher = {Princeton University Press},
  date      = {1969},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\printbiblist{abbreviations}

Die Debatten.\footnote{Siehe hierzu: \cite{Poe:1994} und \cite{Wink:2000}.} Dies gilt analog für die Gegner.\footnote{Siehe hierzu: \cite{Wink:2003}.} Die beiden erwähnten\footnote{Siehe hierzu: \cite{Wink:2003}.} Bezeichnungen als „besonders“\footnote{\cite[1]{Engelmann:2013}.} verstanden werden.\footnote{\cite[Vgl.][1]{Engelmann:2013}. Siehe auch: \cite{peterson:1993}, \cite{Pritchard:1969}.} und \cite{Well19}.}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I recognize that the solution is:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{XXX}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}{\addcolon\space}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {}
  {}
```

And it works quite well (for "XXX", it has to be "book", "article", etc.). But I am wondering that "review" does not work - why?

Comment: I think David Purton has mentioned in response to some of your questions that `biblatex-sbl` does not (yet) support the standard way to deal with this (namely `nametitledelim` as in the linked answer). See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/504377/35864. There is really no pretty way to get this done with versions of `biblatex-sbl` without `nametitledelim`. You will have to patch or modify the drivers. And indeed, earlier questions of yours already contain patches to try and get `nametitledelim` working (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/504238/35864).

Comment: The `cite:review` driver is slightly different to the others. My previous answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504488/87678 shows the appropriate patch for the `review` entry type. Does it not work for you? To determine what the patch must be, you must look through every driver in `sbl.cbx` and change the patch appropriately.  Not all the drivers contain `\newunit\usebibmacro{title}`, so the standard patch mentioned in your question doesn't work.

Comment: Also please note, that the patch command you have above in your MWE is *not* the same as what I have given in previous answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my [previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504488/87678), there is no straight forward way to do this in `biblatex-sbl` yet. From the next release, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28901/87678) will work, but until then you have to patch every single `cite:…` driver from the file `sbl.cbx` and every driver from `sbl.bbx`.

I've gone through the two files and done this for you for every entry type that `biblatex-sbl` supports. But it's not that hard. It's just a matter of reading through the source in `sbl.cbx` and `sbl.bbx`, seeing where the author is printed and replacing the appropriate `\newunit` with the context sensitive `\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}` which we can control independently based on first citation, subsequent citation, and bibliography.

I also added a redefinition of `\namedashpunct` and a patch to the `author` bibmacro to ensure that there is a colon after the name dash in the bibliography as well.

I know that it's frustrating to have to make these changes to `biblatex-sbl`. But you need to remember that the style is explicitly designed to do what the SBL wants and I haven't gone out of my way to make changes easy.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}

% set up nametitledelim in different contexts
\DeclareDelimFormat[none,bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {\addcomma\space}
    {\addcolon\space}}

% also put colon after dash
\renewcommand*{\namedashpunct}{\addcolon\space}
\xpatchbibmacro{author}
  {\renewcommand*{\namedashpunct}{\adddot\space}}
  {\renewcommand*{\namedashpunct}{\addcolon\space}}
  {\message{Patching `author': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `author': Failure^^J}}

% patch citation drivers
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:ancienttext}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:ancienttext': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:ancienttext': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:classictext}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{shorttitlenohyperlink}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{shorttitlenohyperlink}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:classictext': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:classictext': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:article}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:article': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:article': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:book}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:book': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:book': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:suppbook}
  {\usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
   \newunit}
  {\usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
   \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:suppbook': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:suppbook': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:commentary}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:commentary': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:commentary': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:incommentary}
  {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
   \newunit}
  {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
   \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:commentary': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:commentary': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:incollection}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:incollection': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:incollection': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:inlexicon}
  {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
   \newunit}
  {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
   \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:inlexicon': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:inlexicon': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:inreference}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:inreference': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:inreference': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:review}
  {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
   \newunit}
  {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
   \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:review': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:review': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:thesis}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:thesis': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:thesis': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:misc}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:misc': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:misc': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:conferencepaper}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:conferencepaper': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:conferencepaper': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:periodical}
  {\usebibmacro{editor+others}%
   \newunit}
  {\usebibmacro{editor+others}%
   \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:periodical': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:periodical': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:patent}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:patent': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:patent': Failure^^J}}

% patch bibliography drivers
\xpatchbibdriver{ancienttext}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `ancienttext': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `ancienttext': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{article}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `article': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `article': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{book}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `book': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `book': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{suppbook}
  {\usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
   \newunit}
  {\usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
   \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
  {\message{Patching `suppbook': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `suppbook': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{incommentary:short}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `incommentary:short': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `incommentary:short': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `incollection': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `incollection': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{inreference:short}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `inreference:short': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `inreference:short': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{review}
  {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
   \newunit
   \iffieldundef{title}
     {\newunit}}
  {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
   \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \iffieldundef{title}
     {}}
  {\message{Patching `review': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `review': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{thesis}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `thesis': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `thesis': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{misc}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `misc': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `misc': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{conferencepaper}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `conferencepaper': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `conferencepaper': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{periodical}
  {\usebibmacro{editor+others}%
   \newunit}
  {\usebibmacro{editor+others}%
   \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
  {\message{Patching `periodical': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `periodical': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{patent}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `patent': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `patent': Failure^^J}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Engelmann:2013,
  author      = {Engelmann, Hans and Bengelmann, Franz},
  title       = {Die Sicht},
  location    = {Berlin},
  publisher   = {De Gruyter},
  date        = {2013},
  series      = {Gamma Omega, I. Reihe: Alpha},
  shortseries = {GO.A},
  number      = {4},
}
@mvlexicon{TRE,
  editor     = {Schwertner, Siegried M.},
  title      = {Theologische Realenzyklopädie},
  shorttitle = {TRE},
  volumes    = {36},
  location   = {Berlin and New York},
  publisher  = {De Gruyter},
  date       = {1976/2004},
  shorthand  = {TRE}
}
@inlexicon{Poe:1994,
  author = {Poe, Edgar},
  title  = {Art. Dichtung},
  volume = {2},
  pages  = {9--343},
  xref   = {TRE}
}
@review{Well.19,
  author       = {Well, Jan},
  revdauthor   = {Ban, Peter},
  revdtitle    = {Select. Tomus I, Paris 1950},
  journaltitle = {Göttingische gelehrte Anzeigen},
  shortjournal = {GGA},
  volume       = {18,2},
  keywords     = {sekundaer},
  date         = {1826},
  pages        = {14--18},
}
@article{Wink:2000,
  author       = {Wink, Gert},
  title        = {\mkbibquote{Mega}. Anmerkungen},
  shorttitle   = {\mkbibquote{Mega}},
  journaltitle = {Critica storia},
  shortjournal = {Cs},
  volume       = {34,1},
  date         = {2000},
  pages        = {9--24},
  sorttitle    = {Mega. Anmerkungen}
}
@article{Wink:2003,
  author       = {Wink, Gert},
  title        = {\mkbibquote{Mega II}. Anmerkungen},
  shorttitle   = {\mkbibquote{Mega II}},
  journaltitle = {Critica storia},
  shortjournal = {Cs},
  volume       = {41,4},
  date         = {2003},
  pages        = {11--22},
  sortitle     = {Mega II. Anmerkungen}
}
@incollection{peterson:1993,
  author     = {Peterson, David},
  title      = {The Motif of Fulfilment and the Purpose of Luke-Acts},
  shorttitle = {Motif of Fulfilment},
  pages      = {83-104},
  volume     = {1},
  maintitle  = {The Book of Acts in Its First Century Setting},
  editor     = {Winter, Bruce W.},
  location   = {Grand Rapids},
  publisher  = {Eerdmans},
  date       = {1993},
}
@book{Pritchard:1969,
  editor    = {Pritchard, James B.},
  title     = {Ancient Near Eastern Texts Relating to the Old Testament},
  edition   = {3},
  location  = {Princeton},
  publisher = {Princeton University Press},
  date      = {1969},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbiblist{abbreviations}

Die Debatten.\footnote{Siehe hierzu: \cite{Poe:1994} und \cite{Wink:2000}.}
Dies gilt analog für die Gegner.\footnote{Siehe hierzu: \cite{Wink:2003}.} Die
beiden erwähnten\footnote{Siehe hierzu: \cite{Wink:2003}.} Bezeichnungen als
„besonders“\footnote{\cite[1]{Engelmann:2013}.} verstanden
werden.\footnote{\cite[Vgl.][1]{Engelmann:2013}. Siehe auch:
\cite{peterson:1993}, \cite{Pritchard:1969} und \cite{Well.19}.}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: I think there were some misunderstandings: I wanted only in the bibliography (here under the point 'Literatur") after the name a colon, e.g.: Well, Jan: Rezension von Select. Tomus I, Paris 1950, von Peter Ban. GGA 18,2 (1826): 14–18. In your MWE, all bibliographic entries has after the name of the author either a comma or a point - but in the footnotes, you set a colon.  Can you set the colon for the bibliography entry (not in the footnote)? I am trying since hours, but nothing works and I have no idea how to handle with sbl.cbx

Comment: @noname Oh... In your last question you said explicitly you did not want it for the bibliography. The drivers for the bibliography are in `sbl.bbx`. They need to all be patched too.

Comment: yes, I know what I have said, but I changed my mind after receiving the hint that the point after the name in the bibliography is very vexing for German readers. I thought I have articulated it with the posting of this new question clear; it's my fault and please, excuse me!

Comment: My suggested solution works for everything except "thesis" and "inlexicon"

Comment: @noname. OK. I'll will do it later today.

Comment: The thesis drivers are normal and should work without problems. The bibliography driver for `review` has a redundant `\newunit` that should be there, and this needs to be patched out too. SBL does not put inlexicon entry types in the bibliography at all (just the lexicon goes in). Just put `\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}` instead of `\newunit` before `\printfield{title}` in your custom definition. I've updated my answer. Things can be slightly simpler if you want the colon everywhere.

Comment: oh wait... I think you don't want it at all in the foot note now? In that case, just remove all the `cite:…` driver patches.