# Modification biblatex-sbl

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-sbl

I came across an older post (link: [Colon (:) instead of period (.) after author with biblatex sbl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504867/colon-instead-of-period-after-author-with-biblatex-sbl)) and I had a question to that: I really like this style and the proposed questions, but I want to put a colon instead of a point in the "literature" of the articles (e.g. now, the result is: Wink, Gert: ",Mega II". Anmerkungen". Cs 41,4 (2003): 11—22 - I want this: Wink, Gert: ",Mega II". Anmerkungen", Cs 41,4 (2003): 11—22) - As so. who is a beginner of LaTex, I would be very thankful for any help.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}

% set up nametitledelim in different contexts
\DeclareDelimFormat[none,bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {\addcomma\space}
    {\addcolon\space}}

% also put colon after dash
\renewcommand*{\namedashpunct}{\addcolon\space}
\xpatchbibmacro{author}
  {\renewcommand*{\namedashpunct}{\adddot\space}}
  {\renewcommand*{\namedashpunct}{\addcolon\space}}
  {\message{Patching `author': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `author': Failure^^J}}

% patch citation drivers
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:ancienttext}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:ancienttext': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:ancienttext': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:classictext}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{shorttitlenohyperlink}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{shorttitlenohyperlink}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:classictext': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:classictext': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:article}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:article': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:article': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:book}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:book': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:book': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:suppbook}
  {\usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
   \newunit}
  {\usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
   \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:suppbook': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:suppbook': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:commentary}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:commentary': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:commentary': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:incommentary}
  {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
   \newunit}
  {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
   \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:commentary': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:commentary': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:incollection}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:incollection': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:incollection': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:inlexicon}
  {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
   \newunit}
  {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
   \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:inlexicon': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:inlexicon': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:inreference}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:inreference': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:inreference': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:review}
  {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
   \newunit}
  {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
   \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:review': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:review': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:thesis}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:thesis': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:thesis': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:misc}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:misc': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:misc': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:conferencepaper}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:conferencepaper': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:conferencepaper': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:periodical}
  {\usebibmacro{editor+others}%
   \newunit}
  {\usebibmacro{editor+others}%
   \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:periodical': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:periodical': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{cite:patent}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:patent': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `cite:patent': Failure^^J}}

% patch bibliography drivers
\xpatchbibdriver{ancienttext}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `ancienttext': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `ancienttext': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{article}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `article': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `article': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{book}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `book': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `book': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{suppbook}
  {\usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
   \newunit}
  {\usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
   \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
  {\message{Patching `suppbook': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `suppbook': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{incommentary:short}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `incommentary:short': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `incommentary:short': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `incollection': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `incollection': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{inreference:short}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `inreference:short': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `inreference:short': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{review}
  {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
   \newunit
   \iffieldundef{title}
     {\newunit}}
  {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
   \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \iffieldundef{title}
     {}}
  {\message{Patching `review': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `review': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{thesis}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `thesis': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `thesis': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{misc}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `misc': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `misc': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{conferencepaper}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `conferencepaper': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `conferencepaper': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{periodical}
  {\usebibmacro{editor+others}%
   \newunit}
  {\usebibmacro{editor+others}%
   \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
  {\message{Patching `periodical': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `periodical': Failure^^J}}
\xpatchbibdriver{patent}
  {\newunit
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
   \usebibmacro{title}}
  {\message{Patching `patent': Success^^J}}
  {\message{Patching `patent': Failure^^J}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Engelmann:2013,
  author      = {Engelmann, Hans and Bengelmann, Franz},
  title       = {Die Sicht},
  location    = {Berlin},
  publisher   = {De Gruyter},
  date        = {2013},
  series      = {Gamma Omega, I. Reihe: Alpha},
  shortseries = {GO.A},
  number      = {4},
}
@mvlexicon{TRE,
  editor     = {Schwertner, Siegried M.},
  title      = {Theologische Realenzyklopädie},
  shorttitle = {TRE},
  volumes    = {36},
  location   = {Berlin and New York},
  publisher  = {De Gruyter},
  date       = {1976/2004},
  shorthand  = {TRE}
}
@inlexicon{Poe:1994,
  author = {Poe, Edgar},
  title  = {Art. Dichtung},
  volume = {2},
  pages  = {9--343},
  xref   = {TRE}
}
@review{Well.19,
  author       = {Well, Jan},
  revdauthor   = {Ban, Peter},
  revdtitle    = {Select. Tomus I, Paris 1950},
  journaltitle = {Göttingische gelehrte Anzeigen},
  shortjournal = {GGA},
  volume       = {18,2},
  keywords     = {sekundaer},
  date         = {1826},
  pages        = {14--18},
}
@article{Wink:2000,
  author       = {Wink, Gert},
  title        = {\mkbibquote{Mega}. Anmerkungen},
  shorttitle   = {\mkbibquote{Mega}},
  journaltitle = {Critica storia},
  shortjournal = {Cs},
  volume       = {34,1},
  date         = {2000},
  pages        = {9--24},
  sorttitle    = {Mega. Anmerkungen}
}
@article{Wink:2003,
  author       = {Wink, Gert},
  title        = {\mkbibquote{Mega II}. Anmerkungen},
  shorttitle   = {\mkbibquote{Mega II}},
  journaltitle = {Critica storia},
  shortjournal = {Cs},
  volume       = {41,4},
  date         = {2003},
  pages        = {11--22},
  sortitle     = {Mega II. Anmerkungen}
}
@incollection{peterson:1993,
  author     = {Peterson, David},
  title      = {The Motif of Fulfilment and the Purpose of Luke-Acts},
  shorttitle = {Motif of Fulfilment},
  pages      = {83-104},
  volume     = {1},
  maintitle  = {The Book of Acts in Its First Century Setting},
  editor     = {Winter, Bruce W.},
  location   = {Grand Rapids},
  publisher  = {Eerdmans},
  date       = {1993},
}
@book{Pritchard:1969,
  editor    = {Pritchard, James B.},
  title     = {Ancient Near Eastern Texts Relating to the Old Testament},
  edition   = {3},
  location  = {Princeton},
  publisher = {Princeton University Press},
  date      = {1969},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbiblist{abbreviations}

Die Debatten.\footnote{Siehe hierzu: \cite{Poe:1994} und \cite{Wink:2000}.}
Dies gilt analog für die Gegner.\footnote{Siehe hierzu: \cite{Wink:2003}.} Die
beiden erwähnten\footnote{Siehe hierzu: \cite{Wink:2003}.} Bezeichnungen als
„besonders“\footnote{\cite[1]{Engelmann:2013}.} verstanden
werden.\footnote{\cite[Vgl.][1]{Engelmann:2013}. Siehe auch:
\cite{peterson:1993}, \cite{Pritchard:1969} und \cite{Well.19}.}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for. You talk about "colon" and "point" but your examples differ only for the comma and the dot after `Anmerkungen",`/`Anmerkungen".`

Comment: Almost exactly! I want to know what I have to do so that the dot before "Anmerkungen" in the bibliography becomes a comma.

Comment: Note related to the actual question, but generally I'd replace `\footnote{\cite[1]{Engelmann:2013}.}` with the simpler `\footcite[1]{Engelmann:2013}`. Even for more complex citations like `\footnote{\cite[Vgl.][1]{Engelmann:2013}. Siehe auch:
\cite{peterson:1993}, \cite{Pritchard:1969} und \cite{Well.19}.}` there are options like `\footcites[Vgl.][1]{Engelmann:2013}[siehe auch][]{peterson:1993,Pritchard:1969,Well.19}`. Of course if the additional text in the footnote gets too long, it can make sense to go for `\footnote{... \cite{...} ...}` but for short cites, `\footcite` is usually nicer.

Comment: The punctuation between the title and journal title of an `@article` is the default new unit punctuation of the bibliography, which in your case is a full stop/period. You could easily change that to a comma with `\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}`, but that will change many, many periods to commas in the bibliography. Changing only a specific punctuation command is much, much harder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to change all periods of my bibliography (from a dot/full stop to a colon), so your proposal is fitting to my request. However, when I add your proposed line to this example, everything remains as it is (the dot is left unchanged).

Comment: Oh yeah, right, sorry. I didn't actually run the code because I was in a hurry. Turns out `biblatex-sbl` redefines `\newunitpunct` in `\AtBeginPreamble`, so if you want to get in there, you need `\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}}`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you say me what I have to change, when I want to put a "in:" in front of the comma (in the text and in the bibliography)? Thus, instead of "Wink, Gert: ",Mega II". Anmerkungen", Cs 41,4 (2003): 11—22" => Wink, Gert: ",Mega II". Anmerkungen", in: Cs 41,4 (2003): 11—22"? Both systems are quite often used in German studies and I have not yet make a decision which one I will use.